# How to provide user input in java while running the commands using process builder

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to execute maven command(i.e "mvn clean install") using java process builder.  While executing the commands i am reading its value by using buffer reader. 
But my pom.xml has some user inputs which i want to give through my java class.

So is there any way to pass some fixed value for those input field by using java?

Answer (score 0):

According to `ProcessBuilder` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), you can try something like

`ProcessBuilder pb =
   new ProcessBuilder("mvn clean install", "-DuserInput=123");`

Snippet from the link

```
 ProcessBuilder pb =
   new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
```